# Twilio conversation js sdk Conversation.create() is depreceated

Tags: react-hooks, twilio, twilio-conversations

Working with [Twilio conversation-demo](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/conversations-demo/blob/master/src/ConversationsApp.js) app, but 
`ConversationsClient.create(this.state.token);`
`.create` method is depreceated, so how can we initConversations.
And anyone can please help me how to do the sdk in react hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `"@twilio/conversations": "^2.1.0",` creating chat token from the `ConversationsClient.create` is deprecated. you should be creating a `token` from a [server](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/create-tokens) before you can use `client` instance as follows:

import {Client} from '@twilio/conversations'

const client = new Client(token)